# Custom shape object in MS Office

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, ms-office

I want to create some custom shapes for MS Office which we can use in house.
For example I want to create a shape named “carton box” which have three – four default places where user can add some text. 
It is same as other shapes or I would say just like shapes (line, flowchart, arrow etc) in MS office 2007.

Is there any way to create and reuse such a new objects, also if user don’t have these shape in their toolbox and get a document which includes these shapes; he should be able to see it (defiantly in read only).

Background  - I am a .NET developer and also having small knowedge of MS office development in .NET.

Comment: Why is this a Community Wiki?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create your own custom SmartArt. The feature is not very well advertised by Microsoft and it is probably not not too easy to do so.

You might want to check out the following article from MSDN Magazine:

> **[Create Custom SmartArt Graphics For Use In The 2007 Office System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163470.aspx)**

Some free samples to get you started are available on this page: [Loki3 Diagrams](http://diagrams.loki3.com/) .

Comment: I think you are right smartart is not a valid solution. What about custom shapes. Do you have idea about the same???

Comment: Well, simply create the shape and add it as AutoText or QuickPart (building block).